# Removing Outliers within R Works on One Attribute But Not on Second

Tags: r, data-mining, data-cleaning

(Note: this is part of a homework assignment. I am not asking for a solution to the assigned problem, I am just confused by some behavior in R.)

I have a dataset loaded into an R script as a dataframe. After displaying three of the attributes in a boxplot, I have identified the presence of outliers in two of the three. The next step of the assignment is to remove all outliers. I have written code to do this, but it only removes them from the first of the two attributes; the second application of the process doesn't remove any additional records from the dataframe.

I am using the following code, adapted from reading [this R-bloggers post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/01/how-to-remove-outliers-in-r/):

```
# Get quantiles and IQR for each of the two attributes:
ar_quantiles <- quantile(leaf_data$aspect_ratio)
ar_iqr <- IQR(leaf_data$aspect_ratio)
s_quantiles <- quantile(leaf_data$solidity)
s_iqr <- IQR(leaf_data$solidity)

# Aspect Ratio cleanup.
leaf_data <- subset(
    leaf_data,
    leaf_data$aspect_ratio > (ar_quantiles[1] - 1.5 * ar_iqr) &
leaf_data$aspect_ratio < (ar_quantiles[2] + 1.5 * ar_iqr)
)

# Solidity cleanup.
leaf_data <- subset(
    leaf_data,
    leaf_data$solidity > (s_quantiles[1] - 1.5 * s_iqr) &
leaf_data$solidity < (s_quantiles[2] + 1.5 * s_iqr)
)
```

(There was a different method demonstrated in the blog post, but when I switched to that method it left an outlier in the `aspect_ratio` column and still made no change to the `solidity` column.)

Because of my limited R understanding, the only real debugging I've been able to do is to dump the output of `boxplot(leaf_data$solidity, plot = FALSE)$out` before and after the lines that clean up the `solidity` column. But there was no change in the number of the elements returned by that expression (the elements themselves were unchanged as well).

Does this look like a common error/misunderstanding to anyone?

Comment: Why are you removing outliers?

Comment: Because that was part of the assignment specification.

Answer (score 1):

The default quantiles with `quantile` are 0%, 25%, 50%, 75%, 100%.

This means that the quartiles Q1 and Q3 are the second and fourth value in the two vector you obtain.

Since indexes start at 1 it means that you can obtain Q1 with `ar_quantiles[2]` and Q3 with `ar_quantiles[4]`. Currently you're using indexes 1 and 2 and that's certainly what causes the problem.

[edit] Another option is to specify only the quantiles which are needed when calling `quantile`:

```
ar_quantiles <- quantile(leaf_data$aspect_ratio,probs=c(.25,.75))
```

This way the resulting vector contains only positions 1 and 2 and the rest of your code would work.

Note that you can print your quantiles vector like this:

```
print(ar_quantiles)
```

And you can access the documentation for any function like this:

```
?quantile
```

Comment: Thanks. In the sample code I had read, I missed that they had passed a second argument to the `quantile` function. That was half of my problem; the other half was simply not realizing that after I remove the outliers from the second attribute there could then be new outliers as a result.